# Why does tikz change the behavior of \vfil on my first page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plain-tex

Note the way this renders when using `pdftex`.

```
\input eplain
\beginpackages
  \usepackage{url}
  \usepackage{color}
\endpackages

% comment in the following 4 lines
% \input tikz
% \enablehyperlinks
% \definecolor{urlcolor}{rgb}{.2,.4,.6}
% \hlopts{colormodel=,color=urlcolor}

% ... and comment me out
\enablehyperlinks\hlopts{}

\vbox to 0pt{}
\vfil

{\leftmargin=2in\rightmargin=2in
\definexref{anchor}{display}{type} Hi there. This refers to the
\ref{anchor}. This text should be in the center of the page. Right?}

\vfil\eject
\bye
```

The text is in the middle of the page between the top and bottom margins.

If you follow the instructions in the text and comment & uncomment the respective lines, the text will move to near the top of the page. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Which version of `tikz` do you use? There have been problems in the past with `plain` and it should now be fixed in the cvs repository (and in tlcontrib).

Comment: @cjorssen, how can I tell the version? I installed the texlive version from MacPorts, my package manager.

Comment: `\show\pgfversion` after `\input tikz`.

Comment: @cjorssen, I'm using tikz 2.10 (or pgf 2.10, I guess).

Comment: So you should update to the current cvs version (https://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=cvs&group_id=142562).

Comment: @cjorssen Would you make an answer from your comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're describing has been hopefully fixed in the development version of `tikz/pgf`. You can get it from the [cvs repository](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/) or [here](http://perso.enstimac.fr/~gaborit/latex/tikz-pgf.html) if you want a TDS packaged version or, if you're a TeXlive user, from the [tlcontrib texlive repository](http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/).

Comment: This isn't really what I wanted to hear, but it's the right answer. Thanks.